# Get ViewContainerRef from Component

Tags: angular, typescript

i want to create nested component in angular 4

this is chooser component

```
import {InputComponent} from './input/input.component'
import {BlockComponent} from './block/block.component'

export const FormChooser = {
  Block: BlockComponent,
  Input: InputComponent
}
```

this is component builder

```
const component = FormChooser[data.component]
const factory = this.Resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component)

const new_component = this.ViewContainerRef.createComponent(factory)
```

How to get new_component ViewContainerRef ? so i can use code like this

```
const another_new_component = new_component.createComponent(factory) // as ViewContainerRef
```

Thank you...

Comment: @yurzui  already did, that `this.ViewContainerRef` is ViewContainerRef injected from constructor, but i can't found any ViewContainerRef from that component

Comment: The article [Here is how to get ViewContainerRef before @ViewChild query is evaluated](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-how-to-get-viewcontainerref-before-viewchild-query-is-evaluated-f649e51315fb) shows how this can be done

Comment: and do you want `InputComponent` to be a child of `BlockComponent`? because if you do as you ask you will end up with such situation. They will not be siblings

Comment: yes i want `InputComponent` be a child of `BlockComponent`, it already works with @yurzui anwser, inject the `ViewContainerRef` as public inside BlockComponent then access from `instance` of `new_component`

Comment: yes, injecting a vc is a working solution. Only with this approach you can't specify where  exactly in the `BlockComponent` the `InputComponent` should be inserted. The other solution with `ViewChild` will allow you to do that. But that requires waiting for lifecycle hooks. The article I referenced shows how this can be done before the change detection starts. Actually, on my project I'm constructing a tree of components as well but I do it before the change detection starts using the approach described in the article

Answer (score 10):

You can inject `ViewContainer` in constructor of dynamic component

```
class BlockComponent {
  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}

const factory = this.Resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent)

const newComponentRef = this.ViewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
const newComponentVcRef = newComponentRef.instance.vcRef;
```

or use `@ViewChild` to get reference to `ViewContainerRef`

```
 template: '<ng-container #ref></ng-container>'
})
class BlockComponent {
  @ViewChild('ref') vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
}

const factory = this.Resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlockComponent )

const newComponentRef = this.ViewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
const newComponentVcRef = newComponentRef.instance.vcRef;
```

Comment: thanks it works, put the ViewContainerRef inside that block component, so i can access from instance..

Comment: But what do I do if the dynamic components are 3rd party?

Comment: @Avi inheritance? It is not the optimal solution, but should work.

Answer (score 6):

For Angular +8

```
import { InputNumberComponent } from '../input-number/input-number.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('ref', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const comp = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(InputNumberComponent)
    this.vcRef.createComponent(comp)
  }

}
```